# Работа с DOM , динамическое создание таблици , как правильно?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
(function() {
  var options = {
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/users",
    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log("Checking database!");
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log("Data from database loaded!");

    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.length !== 0) {
        var parsedData = toJsObject(data);
        createTableSchema(parsedData);
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      var error_block = $("<div><h3 style='text-align: center'>Can't load data from database , can't connect to database!<h3/></div>");
      error_block.appendTo("#error").addClass("error");
    },
    async: true,
    method: 'GET'
  };
  $.ajax(options);
})();

function toJsObject(object) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
}

function createTableSchema(data) {
  var currentTable = $("#loginTable");
  var row = $("<tr></tr>").addClass("table-bordered");
  var td = $("<td></td>").addClass("text-center");

  for (var index in data) {
    var objLength = Object.keys(data[index]).length; //4
    var obj = data[index]; //get each object
    while (objLength > 0) {
      td.appendTo(row);
      objLength--;
    }
    row.appendTo(currentTable);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-responsive" id="loginTable">
      <tr class="table-bordered table-striped">
        <th class="text-center">NICKNAME</th>
        <th class="text-center">EMAIL</th>
        <th class="text-center">PASSWORD</th>
        <th>ID</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-bordered">
        <td class="text-center">data</td>
        <td class="text-center">data</td>
        <td class="text-center">data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="error"></div>
```

При проверки в браузере в Elements : Я получаю  только одно присоединение ,
что не хватает в алгоритме в методе createTableSchema .. ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: думаю тут проблема именно в том, что один раз создан объект и в него  попытка записать постоянно.... а надо постоянно новые создавать.... то есть и `$("<tr></tr>")` и `$("<td></td>")` надо в циклы воткнуть

Comment: Вы мне пример кода можете дать как ответ ?

Comment: Ну там в принципе ничего особенного. Я конечно написал. Но вроде и так ясно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю тут проблема именно в том, что один раз создан объект и в него попытка записать постоянно.... а надо постоянно новые создавать.... то есть и `$("<tr></tr>")` и `$("<td></td>")` надо поместить в соответствущие циклы

```js
var currentTable = $("#loginTable");
 
    
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { // for (var index in data) {
    var row = $("<tr></tr>").addClass("table-bordered");
    var objLength = 4; // var objLength = Object.keys(data[index]).length; 
    //var obj = data[index]; //get each object
    while (objLength > 0) {
        var td = $("<td></td>").addClass("text-center");
        td.appendTo(row);
        objLength--;
    }
    
    row.appendTo(currentTable);
}
```

```css
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive" id="loginTable"></table>
```